# How to run a docker container for localhost/already existing database, without creating any mysql server?

Tags: java, mysql, docker

I am very new to docker,
I have a jar file of simple java app which connects to the database on `localhost:3306`, I don't want to create any new docker mysql server, I want my app to be connected with my existing database.
I want to run this jar from docker. My Dockerfile is

```
 FROM java:8  
     COPY . /var/www/java  
     WORKDIR /var/www/java  
     CMD ["java", "-jar","exp.jar"]
```

but it is showing error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
   Communications link failure Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms
   ago. at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
   Method) at
   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at
   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at
   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) at
   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
   at
   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2103)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718) at
   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46) at
   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   at
   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at
   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at
   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) at
   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302) at
   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) at
   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) at
   com.linkeztech.code.App.main(App.java:37) Caused by:
   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

What do I do for it? I'm stuck please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: what is you host machine os? mac, linux, windows?

Answer (score 1):

**Linux Host**

Start the container using the network mode host. `docker run --network host ...`. This will make the container share the network stack with the host. Thus a connection to `localhost:3306` from the container will connect to the database.

**Docker for MAC**

From inside the application container connect to `docker.for.mac.localhost:3306` rather than `localhost:3306`. `docker.for.mac.localhost` is a special DNS name that will resolve to the IP of the host machine.

**Docker for Windows**

Run **ipconfig** on the windows machine and find the IP address for `Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT)` network interface. Use that IP to connect to the database.